# How to properly specify path to a file in node.js in Linux?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to read a file:

```
fs.readFileSync('~/node_modules/.bin/lasttest.txt', "UTF-8");
```

But it tells me that *no such file or directory*.

But if I use the command: `sudo nano ~/node_modules/.bin/send.js` the file opens.

Comment: Did you try using the absolute path instead?

Comment: The `~` is expanded by your shell, which is why `sudo nano ~/…` works. Find some way of expanding tildes in Node, or use an absolute path.

Comment: I found an npm package that expands tilde https://www.npmjs.com/package/expand-tilde think i will use it, I don't want to use absolute path because I want this code to be easy to transfer

Answer (score 0):

Well, '~' resoles to home directory of a user.

if you are logged-in with user=XYZ
ls ~/abc.txt

it run with user XYZ, and its home might be /home/XYZ, it looks for this file in /home/XYZ/abc.txt

When you run it with sudo,
sudo ls ~/abc.txt

Now, it is NOT running as XYZ user, it is running as root.
Which means, it wil have a different home directory, say: /root/

so, it is running 
ls /root/abc.txt